# Show something that was hidden by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code for a small jQuery game I'm making, and all the pictures (characters) are hidden by default. There's a question that says "Are you ready to play?" and a yes or no button. When you click the yes button, it hides the buttons and the text. It is also supposed to display the first image, which is #main. For some reason, it's not working.
Here's the jQuery code with the images under:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#main,#batman,#car,#hobo,#knife,#gangfight,#ganggun,#gangknife,#blood').hide(-100);  
var main=$('#main');  
 batman=$('#batman');  
 car=$('#car');
 hobo=$('#hobo');
 cop=$('#cop');
 knife=$('#knife');
 gangfight=$('#gangfight');
 ganggun=$('#ganggun');
 gangknife=$('#gangknife');
 blood=$('#blood');
    document.write('<title>LOAUP</title>');
    document.write('<center><h1>The life of an unlucky person</h1></center>');
    document.write('<center id="start">Are you ready to play?</center>');
    document.write('<center><button id="yes">Yes</button><button id="no">No</button></center>');
    $('#yes').click(function(){
        $('#yes,#no').hide(function(){
            $('#start').hide();
            $('#main').show
        });
        });
    $('#no').click(function(){
        $('#yes,#no').hide();
        $('#start').hide();
        document.write('<center>Ok, come back another time then.</center>');
    });
});
//Images below this (HTML)
<img id='main' src='/jquery/sprites/spritePerson.png' />
    <img id='batman' src='/jquery/sprites/spriteBatman.png' />
    <img id='car' src='/jquery/sprites/spriteCar.png' />
    <img id='hobo' src='/jquery/sprites/spriteHobo.png' />
    <img id='cop' src='/jquery/sprites/spriteCop.png' />
    <img id='knife' src='/jquery/sprites/spriteKnife.png' />
    <img id='gangfight' src='/jquery/sprites/spriteGangFight.png' />
    <img id='ganggun' src='/jquery/sprites/spriteGangGun.png' />
    <img id='gangknife' src='/jquery/sprites/spriteGangKnife.png' />
    <img id='blood' src='/jquery/sprites/spriteBloodPuddle.png' />
```

**Edit:**

Here's the example:
http://jsbin.com/ocowas/1

Comment: You're making lots of global variables. You either need to separate your variables with a comma, or put `var ` before each one.

Comment: ...and don't use `document.write` after the DOM has loaded. This destroys the existing DOM.

Comment: what else do I use to display text?

Comment: Depending on what exactly you're displaying, either `$("#elem").text(text_here)` or `$("#elem").html(text_here)`

Comment: @user2036003 if you are using jQuery anyway you can use `.html()` or `.text()`

Comment: Amongst other things you're missing the brackets after show. Show is a function, $('#main').show()

Comment: You need to create DOM elements, and append them. You can do this with jQuery if you're already using it, but I'd suggest learning how to do it with the native API. For example: `var t = document.createElement("title"); t.innerHTML = "LAOUP"; document.body.appendChild(t);`

Comment: @laurencek I just noticed that, didn't change anything. Can someone please answer my first question? I will make sure to make dom elements and stuff

Comment: The `document.write` issue is the main problem. It's destroying the page.

Comment: You guys make me feel so stupid <3

Comment: didn't you even look at the errors flagged by jsbin ? Also syntax errors in code

Comment: I did, but it said warning. I didn't know what eval meant, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your #main click function change

```
$('#main').show
```

to

```
$('#main').show();
```

Your variable list should be comma seperated not colon seperated. and you may also want to rename your variables to make them more obvious and easier to read/remember by prefixing with a $ sign. For example when you store a selector as a variable use

```
var $element = $('#element'),
    $element2 = $('#element2'),
    $element23 = $('#element23');
```

Further, the hide() function does not take negative numbers as you have used. Just use hide() for an instant hide, or hide(100) for fast, hide(2000) for slow.. check: http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/hide

To append html to your document without using document.write, you can store the html as a variable, then select the body tag, or any other tag and append/prepend or replace the html to that, for example.

```
$('body').append(yourHTMLvar);
$('body').prepend(yourHTMLvar);
$('body').html(yourHTMLvar);
```

The 'title' tag should only appear between the 'head' tags of your html document. Use a heading tag instead, 'h1' to 'h6'.
The html 'center' tag is also deprecated as far as I know. Try using 'span', 'p' or even 'div' instead.

Comment: `$('#main').show` isn't a syntax error. It just requests the value of the `.show` property without utilizing it.